# how to calculate success of procurement with value and count of competitors

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have collected data for procurements and I would like to calculate success for a contractor on each procurement and then create "index of success" on these data.
What I have is count of competitors and money value which contractor earned.
I dont want to calculate just simple % from count of competitors like

```
 100 - (1/number of competitors)*100
```

because it doesnt tell much if contractor fought against 3 competitors in procurement for 20000€ or if he fought against 20 competitors in procurement for 20 million € . I would like to add weight to each procurement according value in € but dont know how.

Could somebody help me with an idea how to approach this?
thanks